# How to make the detailview and masterView communicate in the splitViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitView` with a `masterView` and a `detailView`. The `masterView` is a `UITableViewController` (inside a `UINavigationControler`) and the `detailView` is a `UIViewController` (also inside a `UINavaigationController`).

The `UISplitView` appears just fine with the `masterView` and an empty `detailView`. In `masterView`, I have this method:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       if (![self splitViewController])
       DetailViewController*myDetailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
       Item *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
       [myDetailView setItem:selectedItem];
       [[self navigationController] pushViewController:myDetailView animated:YES];
    }
```

This works fine for iPhone.
For iPad, the `detailView` appears in the `masterViewController`, allbeit correctly, but the detailview remains empty.

How can I make  `myDetailview` appear in the `detailView` (right side of the `splitView`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use Matt gemmell's [`MGSplitViewController`](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController)

He has customized everything in the split view controller, you can get the master at right side using this and its just weird that you said that `UISplitViewController` is working fine in iPhone

To be clear `UISplitViewController` is specific for iPad and not for iPhone

So, please have a knowledge of iPad specific controllers like `UIPopOverController` and `UISplitViewController`

In Doc's, you can read this in the first line it self

```
Split view controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices.

 Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into MGSplitViewController. I think I was unclear when I said it worked fine for iPhone. I ment the code worked for iPhone (!if[self splitViewController]). Meaning that the iPhone ignores the UISplitviewcontroller and presents the detailview on top of the masterview.